# What is the use of java trace in the jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, trace

When I export a JAR file, I noticed that it has .java._trace files in it. What is the purpose of this file? Is there a setting in eclipse that will allow me to disable this file so that it will not be included in the JAR file?

Answer (score 1):

these files contain debug stratum information
(see com.sun.jdi.Location.lineNumber(stratum) in tools.jar)
for example they are generated by xtext when using
a JVM Model Inferrer.  line numbers are mapped from 
the derived file in your custom language to the generated java file,
that way you can debug the custom language file directly.